# Unicorn error on Azure Paas

Tags: paas, unicorn

We have been deploying our Sitecore 9.0.1 to Azure Paas, deploying each time to a clean slot. On the last deploy Unicorn synch stopped working, we are even unable to open the Unicorn.aspx page.
Unicorn version 4.0.0

We tried full rollback deploying earlier (previously working) version of our solution on a clean slot but the error persists.

It works if deployed on an previously created Web app, but not on a new one.
Any ideas on where to look would be appreciated.

Error from log

> ERROR: Method not found: Void Rainbow.Storage.Sc.Deserialization.DefaultDeserializer..ctor(Rainbow.Storage.Sc.Deserialization.IDefaultDeserializerLogger, Rainbow.Filtering.IFieldFilter). (System.MissingMethodException)<div class="stacktrace">at Unicorn.Deserialization.UnicornDeserializer..ctor(IDefaultDeserializerLogger logger, IFieldFilter fieldFilter) 
>   Info  at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] ) 
>   Info  at Configy.Containers.MicroContainer.Activate(Type type, KeyValuePair`2[] unmappedConstructorParameters) 
>   Info   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() 
>   Info  at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() 
>   Info  at Configy.Containers.MicroContainer.Resolve(Type type) 
>   Info at Configy.Containers.MicroContainer.Activate(Type type, KeyValuePair`2[] unmappedConstructorParameters) 
>   Info  at Unicorn.Configuration.ConfigyConfigurationProvider.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<RegisterConfigTypeInterface>b__1() 
>   Info  at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() 
>   Info  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() 
>   Info at System.Lazy`1.get_Value() 
>   Info  at Unicorn.Data.Dilithium.DilithiumExtensions.EnablesDilithiumSql(IConfiguration configuration) 
>   Info   at Unicorn.SerializationHelper.SyncConfigurations(IConfiguration[] configurations, IProgressStatus progress, ILogger additionalLogger)</div>

Comment: have a look on this solution: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/793/cannot-save-a-sitecore-item-the-error-message-says-the-parent-item-was-not-seri

Comment: Since it is writing **Method Not Found** , you can try comparing the versions of Dlls' related to unicorn .

Comment: Your configs and Unicorn DLLs are out of sync.